# Spring Boot aspectj compile time weaving - JPA Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I am using Spring Boot application with compile time weaving of Aspects with AspectJ. Am facing an issue while annotating methods in JPA Repositories, these methods are not getting intercepted.

Is there any solution for this.

Aspect am using is

```
@Aspect
public class ReplicaOnlyInterceptor {

    @Around("@annotation(xxx.xxx.ReplicaOnly) && execution(* xxx.xxx..*(..))")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("ReplicaOnly :" + pjp.toShortString());
        Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Repository is

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Config, Long> {

    @ReplicaOnly
    public Person findByName(String name);
}
```

While calling the method PersonRepository#findByName, the ReplicaOnlyInterceptor is not getting invoked

Comment: If you want a solution, you should start by presenting the problem in a way that allows reproducing it.

Comment: @mkl i had added more details, can you please check now.